# How to get text from html attributes

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath, lxml.html

I tried to parse a page to get some element as text, but I cant find how to get text from select

For exmaple, html below has data-initial-rating="4" and title="Members who rated this thread">12 Votes", but I cant get it

```
<select name="rating" class="br-select input" data-xf-init="rating" data-initial-rating="4" data-rating-href="/threads/isis-the-fall-v1-02-tjord.117157/br-rate" data-readonly="false" data-deselectable="false" data-show-selected="true" data-widget-class="bratr-rating" data-vote-content="<div data-href=&quot;/threads/game-mod-v-1-02/br-user-rated&quot; data-xf-click=&quot;overlay&quot; data-xf-init=&quot;tooltip&quot; title=&quot;Members who rated this thread&quot;>12 Votes</div>" style="display: none;">
                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="1">Terrible</option>
<option value="2">Poor</option>
<option value="3">Average</option>
<option value="4">Good</option>
<option value="5">Excellent</option>

            </select>
```

what i tried

```
import requests
import lxml.html


response = requests.get('somewebsite.com')
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
# full xptah
messy_rating_and_votes = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/select')
print(messy_rating_and_votes) # its just print empty list, so i cant use .text or .text_content()
```

So, i guese thats i select wrong or use wrong method, but almost 2 hours of googling dosent help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses BeautifulSoup4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("somewebsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')  # requires pip install html5lib

for option in soup.find_all('option'):
    print(f"value: {option['value']} text: {option.text}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for recomended bs, its works now perfectly

Answer (score 0):

We can't judge the correctness of your XPath because you didn't include the full document. You might have made a small error anywhere in that path, e.g. `div[3]` when it should have been `div[2]`, for instance.

You might try a simpler path using the `descendant` axis (with syntactic shortcut `//`) instead of the default `child` axis. This would enable you to skip over much the document's messy structure. e.g.

```
//select[@name='rating']
```

or

```
//select[@name='rating'][@data-xf-init='rating']
```

... or however specific you need to be to identify that particular `select` element.

Comment: Its cant be a error, because I use crome XPath extension to copy Xpath from html, but thanks for advice